# Is this sequence convergent? If so, then how to find the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

For each natural number $n$, let
$$ x_n \colon= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}  + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right). $$

Then is the sequence $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ convergent? And if so, then how to find the limit of this sequence?

I'm just not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: Are you studying series? In what section did this arise? Are you allowed to use integrals to approximate sums? What have you tried? Please provide context.

Answer (score 7):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:  USE CREATIVE TELESCOPING**

since $\frac12(\sqrt {k-1}+\sqrt k)\le \sqrt k\le \frac12(\sqrt {k+1}+\sqrt k)$, we can use creative telescoping to write

$$\sum_{k=1}^n2\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k\right)\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\le 1+\sum_{k=2}^n 2\left(\sqrt k-\sqrt{k-1}\right)$$

Evaluating the telescoping terms reveals

$$2(\sqrt {n+1}-1)\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\le 2\sqrt n-1$$

whence dividing by $\sqrt n$ and applying the squeeze theorem yields the result

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac1{\sqrt  n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt k}=2$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:  APPLY STOLZ-CESARO**

Using the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), we find that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt k}}{\sqrt n}&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)\\\\
&=2
\end{align}$$

Comment: On the first line, what happened to the $k=1$ term on the RHS? On the second line, the LHS should be $2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)$, and the RHS should be the same (due to the missing $k=1$ term).

Comment: @Bungo The first term is explicitly written as $1$, which is why the summation on the RHS begins at $k=2$.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't notice that. Looks good now. (+1)

Comment: @Bungo Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This sequence does converge. For every positive integer $n$, since $x \mapsto 1/\sqrt{x}$ is decreasing, we have
$$ \int_0^{n} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} > \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} >\int_1^{n+1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} \\
2 \sqrt{n} > \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} >2 (\sqrt{n+1}-1) \\
2  >\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} >2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \to 2 $$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: $\int x^{-1/2}\,dx=2x^{1/2}$, not ${1\over2}x^{1/2}$.

Comment: D'oh, of course...

Comment: You have the first inequality the wrong way.